# List in a List or Tuples

Tags: python

I have a bunch of audio files

```
('ZOOM0001_LR.WAV',
'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV',
'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_LR.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_TR1.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_TR3.WAV')
```

What I want to do is group Zoom0001_XX files into a list in the list and Zoom0002_XX into the list as well and so forth.

```
files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\adam\Music\temp_h6','*.wav')))
```

I'm not sure if list is teh way to go or should I use Tuples.

End goal is for me to process the files in the list of lists individually as well as mixing the set of 3 (Zoom001_LR, TR1, TR3) files.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see the connection between your list & your code, much less what any of it has to do with your "end goal".

Comment: Add far as functionality is concerned, there is little difference between a list and a tuple, except that a tuple is immutable. On the other hand, semantically, it is usually best to use a list to hold any number of elements of the same type and to use a tuple to hold a fixed number of elements which may be of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is that you can sort the files into a dictionary and then loop through all keys/values.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

files = ('ZOOM0001_LR.WAV',
'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV',
'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_LR.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_TR1.WAV',
'ZOOM0002_TR3.WAV')

organized_files = defaultdict(list)

for filename in files:
    key = filename.split('_')[0]
    organized_files[key].append(filename)

# organized_files is now {'ZOOM0001': ['ZOOM0001_LR.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV'], 'ZOOM0002': ['ZOOM0002_LR.WAV', 'ZOOM0002_TR1.WAV', 'ZOOM0002_TR3.WAV']}


for file_group in organized_files.values():
    # ['ZOOM0001_LR.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV']
    print(file_group)
    for f in file_group:
        # do whatever you need to do for each file in this group of "ZOOM001_*" files
        ...
```

Comment: this is eactly what i was looking for, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your list of files you can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

files = ('ZOOM0001_LR.WAV',
         'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV',
         'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV',
         'ZOOM0002_LR.WAV',
         'ZOOM0002_TR1.WAV',
         'ZOOM0002_TR3.WAV')

result = []
for _, group in grouby(files, key=lambda name: name[:8]):
    result.append(list(group))

print(result)
```

output:

```
[['ZOOM0001_LR.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR1.WAV', 'ZOOM0001_TR3.WAV'],
 ['ZOOM0002_LR.WAV', 'ZOOM0002_TR1.WAV', 'ZOOM0002_TR3.WAV']]
```

Comment: verified that this also works for me.  Thanks!